# SharePoint Content Editor HTML textbox Enter key leading to Edit mode of Page

Tags: 2013, 2010, content-editor-web-part, html, inputformtextbox

While using HTML Textbox in content editor and from Chrome or Mozilla User presses Enter key leading to edit mode of the page. Issue with SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

// SharePoint input element bug handler
// More bug: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/33df42ba-00b3-41a8-8fb9-f8187cfc216d/strange-behavior-in-firefox-input-text-with-enter-opens-page-for-editing?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious
// This fix stops form submit => blocks transfer to edit mode

var disableFormSubmitDueToBug = false;
var bugSubmitHandlerAttached = false;

$('text box id or class').keydown(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13 ) { 
  disableFormSubmitDueToBug = true;
  bindBugSubmitHandler();
} else {
  unbindBugSubmitHandler();
}
}).focusout(function(){
unbindBugSubmitHandler();
});

function bindBugSubmitHandler(){
$( "form" ).bind("submit", function( e ) {
if(disableFormSubmitDueToBug) {
e.preventDefault();
console.log('Blocked submit by SP bug handler');
}
bugSubmitHandlerAttached = true;
});
}

function unbindBugSubmitHandler(){
if(bugSubmitHandlerAttached){
$( "form" ).unbind("submit");
bugSubmitHandlerAttached = false;
console.log('SP bug submit handler unbind occurred');
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is a workaround method and will also disable edit link on the page.Found the issue after implementation of same

Comment: Author of this snippet is Jouko Nyholm. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33df42ba-00b3-41a8-8fb9-f8187cfc216d/strange-behavior-in-firefox-input-text-with-enter-opens-page-for-editing?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but the edit page will fire on the keydown event instead of the keyup event. Move your e.preventDefault(); to the keydown for 13, and your good to go. I wouldn't have even found this page if I had been using keydown instead of keyup, as it would have worked as intended.